Codigniter database connection to Digital Ocean DB
From Codeigniter 3, I am unable to connect to Digital Ocean Managed MysQL database. I can connect MySQL from terminal of any allowed instance AND native PHP works as well but not from Codeigniter "database.php" file. Digital Ocean DB requires SSL and provided a "ca-certificate.crt" file. After configuring it returns the below error but all info is correct.
"Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings."
Here is the configuration file-
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'example.db.com'; //example
$db['default']['port']     =  25060; //real port
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_set'] = TRUE;    
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_key'] = NULL;   
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_cert'] = NULL;   
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_ca'] =   
realpath('./application/third_party/ca-certificate.crt');   
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_capath'] = NULL;   
$db['default']['encrypt']['ssl_cipher'] = NULL;
$db['default']['username'] = 'demouser'; 
$db['default']['password'] = 'demopasswd';
$db['default']['database'] = 'defaultdb';   
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; 
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = ''; 
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; 
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE; 
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE; 
$db['default']['cachedir'] = ''; 
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8'; 
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = ''; 
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

I search but didn't find the solution.
Can anyone give me some insight.
Thank you

Can you edit index.php at the root of your project and put your ENVIRONMENT to development so we can see more logs?
